# How to keep angle of DropShadow when node is rotated

Tags: javafx, dropshadow

When you apply a DropShadow on a node which is rotated, then the DropShadow rotates with it. Is there a simple way to keep the DropShadow angle where it is, e. g. bottom right even when the node is rotated?

I know that it would work if I put all the nodes into a group and apply the shadow on the group, but that's unfortunately not an option in my case.

Sample image:

- left rectangle with drop shadow
- right rectangle with same drop shadow, but rotated by 180 degrees

[image]

You see, it looks wrong with the shadows being in opposite directions.

Code

```
public class HelloEffects extends Application {

    Stage stage;
    Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Group group = new Group();

        DropShadow ds1 = new DropShadow();
        ds1.setOffsetY(4.0f);
        ds1.setOffsetX(4.0f);
        ds1.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle( 100, 200);
        rect1.relocate(100, 100);
        rect1.setEffect(ds1);
        rect1.setFill(Color.RED);

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle( 100, 200);
        rect2.relocate(300, 100);
        rect2.setEffect(ds1);
        rect2.setFill(Color.RED);
        rect2.setRotate(180);

        group.getChildren().addAll(rect1, rect2);

        scene = new Scene( group, 840, 680);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: i do not know if that is possible,since applying `Effect` and `Rotation` will not change the relative bounds but the transformation bounds so unless you undo that then that-which means no rotation i guest that will be your solution. That is to my understanding

Answer (score 1):

You should add a container to rect2 and apply the effect on the container, the container can be either Pane or Group:

```
Group rect2Container = new Group(rect2);
rect2Container.setEffect(ds1);
group.getChildren().addAll(rect1, rect2Container);
```

Comment: Never thought it'd be so easy. Brilliant!